# Show a toast containing the whole text on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, toast

There is a text that is longer than the accepted width and it must be shown truncated, just show a part of it and three dots and the end.

This part works fine. What I want is to show the whole text when hovering over it into a toast while also keeping the original truncated text under it.

think that a toaster-like notification box is what would look good in this case.

At the moment it shows the whole text on hover but it covers completely the truncated one. Is there a way to do it?

```css
.product-details {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 120px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.product-details:hover {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-details">this is a very very long text of course
</div>
```

Comment: You can't preserve truncated text concurrently showing the full text on hover just using CSS. Or you have to add two html elements: 1 for short desc, 1 for full desc. Otherwise you should use JS

Comment: @MaksimL, if there are two elements, how do we show one of them when the other one is hovered? I mean, this is how I understand it can be done

Comment: One element is hidden by default, when we hover over the other element, the hidden is displayed

Comment: @MaksimL how can be done to display an element when another one is hovered?

Comment: Jean Pierre, see the bellow example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.product-details {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 120px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-details:hover + .product-details-full {

  width: 120px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  white-space: normal;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block
}

.product-details-full {
 display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="product-details">this is a very very long text of course
   
</div>
<div class="product-details-full">this is a very very long text of course
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the text to the title attribute and it will show automatically on hover with no additional code. i.e:

```
<div title="This is some long text that will not fit in the box">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>
```